# return status value of a shell script when called from ruby?

Tags: ruby

I expected these values to match. They did not match when the shell script exited due to some error condition (and thus returned a non-zero value). Shell $? returned 1, ruby $? returned 256.

```
>> %x[ ls kkr]
ls: kkr: No such file or directory
=> ""
>> puts $?
256
=> nil
>> exit
Hadoop:~ Madcap$ ls kkr
ls: kkr: No such file or directory
Hadoop:~ Madcap$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: What version of Ruby? In 1.9.2-p180, `$?.exitstatus` returns the same value as `$?` in the shell for me. And in 1.8.7-p334, and 1.9.3-p0. What OS?

Comment: Yeah, I get `#<Process::Status: pid 23365 exit 1>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Ruby `$?` is a `Process::Status` instance. Printing `$?` is equivalent to calling `$?.to_s`, which is equivalent to `$?.to_i.to_s` (from the documentation).

`to_i` is not the same as `exitstatus`.

From the documentation:

> Posix systems record information on processes using a 16-bit integer.
>   The lower bits record the process status (stopped, exited, signaled)
>   and the upper bits possibly contain additional information (for
>   example the program's return code in the case of exited processes).

`$?.to_i` will display this whole 16-bit integer, but what you want is just the exit code, so for this you need to call `exitstatus`:

```
$?.exitstatus
```

Comment: What do you mean by call exitstatus how can I do that? I get `pid 27305 exit 1` as output I just want that 1 other that parsing what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html:

> The value of status may be 0, EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE, [CX]   or any other value, though only the least significant 8 bits (that is, status & 0377) shall be available to a waiting parent process.

The unix exit status only has 8 bit. 256 overflows so I guess the behavior in that case is simply undefined. For example this happens on Mac OS 10.7.3 with Ruby 1.9.3:

```
irb(main):008:0> `sh -c 'exit 0'`; $?
=> #<Process::Status: pid 64430 exit 0>
irb(main):009:0> `sh -c 'exit 1'`; $?
=> #<Process::Status: pid 64431 exit 1>
irb(main):010:0> `sh -c 'exit 2'`; $?
=> #<Process::Status: pid 64432 exit 2>
irb(main):011:0> `sh -c 'exit 255'`; $?
=> #<Process::Status: pid 64433 exit 255>
irb(main):012:0> `sh -c 'exit 256'`; $?
=> #<Process::Status: pid 64434 exit 0>
```

Which is consistent with what my shell indicates

```
$ sh -c 'exit 256'; echo $?
0 
$ sh -c 'exit 257'; echo $?
1
```

I'd propose you fix the shell-script (if possible) to return only values < 256.